# Org-Mode: Image get corrupted in result

Tags: emacs, org-mode, org-babel

I am using **Emacs Org-Mode** and I am trying to fetch a picture from the web using **wget** and display it as an inline image in a code block result. So, I write the following block of code:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :results file :file ~/image.jpg
url='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brettlangdon/85942af486eb79118467/raw/2a7409cd3c26a90b2e82bdc40dc7db18b92b3517/06b3FMA.jpg'
wget "$url" -O ~/image.jpg
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
[[file:~/image.jpg]]
```

However, the image is not display and get corrupted. In console I get:

> Premature end of JPEG file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC bash
 url='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brettlangdon/85942af486eb79118467/raw/2a7409cd3c26a90b2e82bdc40dc7db18b92b3517/06b3FMA.jpg'
 wget "$url" -O ~/image.jpg
 #+END_SRC
```

Executes script, downloading the specified URL to `~/image.jpg`

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC bash :results file :file ~/image.jpg
 url='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brettlangdon/85942af486eb79118467/raw/2a7409cd3c26a90b2e82bdc40dc7db18b92b3517/06b3FMA.jpg'
 wget "$url" -O ~/image.jpg
 #+END_SRC
```

Executes script, downloading the specified URL to `~/image.jpg`, and then writes the standard output from the shell command to `~/image.jpg` (which I expect leaves you with an *empty* file, as wget writes information to stderr).

So you can either use the first approach and include your image link independently of the code block; or if you want the downloaded image data to be captured in the `:results` you need to tell wget to write to stdout.

```
 #+BEGIN_SRC bash :results file :file ~/image.jpg
 url='https://gist.githubusercontent.com/brettlangdon/85942af486eb79118467/raw/2a7409cd3c26a90b2e82bdc40dc7db18b92b3517/06b3FMA.jpg'
 wget "$url" -O -
 #+END_SRC
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it works well. I didn't know that image are read directly from stdout O.o

Comment: tbh, having had a look at `(org)results`, I'm not sure why that's the case without an explicit `:results output file`; however it does seem to be what happens in practice.